# Detect multitouch in a custom UIViewController contains a UITableView subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, multi-touch

I have a UITableView as a subview in the UIViewController's view. I understand that I can detect the touch event by overwritting

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];  
}
```

But it never detected these events in the `ViewController` if I touched the `tableview`. As suggested in this forum by others, I should had a custom `UITableView` and added the above lines in it. I did that, but still the `viewController` did not detect the touch event. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of Googling, I finally found the solution that works for me. The key is to pass the responder chain to the next responder. For instance, in the touch began case, add the following line. 
[self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]